# nginx: Index file outside of the document root

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve a directory of user-provided files with nginx, but with an index file that is outside of the document root. The reason I don't want to locate the index file inside the directory is because the directory is meant for users to drop their stuff in there.

Nginx's `index` directive seems to only work for files inside the document root; the documentation says that the index can be an "absolute path", but my experiments tell that this is only relative to the document root.

So, I tried to serve another index location with `location =/index.html { alias /path/to/index.html }`, and this manages to work when `/index.html` is directly requested, but it doesn't work if `/` is requested (403 with log "directory index of "/srv/docroot/" is forbidden"). It starts to work, though, if I create an empty file to `/srv/docroot/index.html`; then `/path/to/index.html` is served at `/`. So it seems that Nginx

1. Checks if `/srv/docroot/index.html` file exists in the filesystem at the `/`'s location.
2. If it exists, it does an internal redirect, and serves the `/path/to/index.html` at `/index.html` location.

What is the correct way to serve an index file outside of the document root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` and `try_files` directives, provided with absolute paths, seem only to be able to point to the files inside the current document root. (With relative `../` paths you can point outside of the document root, but that's not ideal if you want to point to an absolute path in the filesystem.)

It seems that only the `alias` directive can point outside the document root. I was able to get my setup to work with:

```
...
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location =/index.html {
            alias /path/to/index.html;
        }
...
```

This doesn't strictly answer to the question in the sense, that in this case, `index.html` isn't shown only when `/` is requested, but always when a matching file isn't found. I'm happy with this solution, but it might make sense in some cases to separate the 404 error.